# iOS Development: How can I force a UIWebView to load the non-mobile version of Facebook?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad

I'm diving into iOS development and when I try to load a specific Facebook Fan Page in a UIWebView, it loads the mobile version of the site, which only loads the wall of the Fan Page instead of a specific tab that I need loaded.  In the iPad version of my app, the UIWebView loads the normal, non-mobile version of Facebook and it loads the tab just fine.  How can I force the UIWebView on the iPhone to load the normal version of Facebook?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Facebook is most likely analyzing the user agent to determine which version to serve. If this is the case then changing the user agent to a desktop browser user agent would cause facebook to change which page version is served. You can change the user agent on NSMutableURLRequest like so:

```
[request setValue:@"some-user-agent" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
```

Comment: Thanks, jaminguy, that worked!  By the way, when setting the user agent field, you have to use "User_Agent".  When reading the user agent field, you use "User-Agent" (note the underscore in the first).

Comment: Also, for anyone struggling to figure out which value to set, here's the code I used...
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Safari/528.16", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];

Answer (score 0):

Do this in viewDidLoad (or somewhere else before loading UIWebView):

```
NSDictionary *userAgent = @{ @"UserAgent" : @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0" };
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userAgent];
```