# Force SFSafariViewController to load the desktop version of a website

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

As the title suggests, I was wondering if there is a way to force SFSafariViewController to load the desktop version of a website.

Thanks

Comment: check this .. add this in your request...  [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Safari/528.16", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];   http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065794/2714702

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but there is no way to set a NSURLRequest on SFSafariViewController... your solution works only for a UIWebView. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 9, sadly no. Your best bet might be to create your own web view and use a different user agent as @vizllx suggests in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WKWebView and then set the customUserAgent property of the web view to any desktop browser user-agent.

Comment: If you have control over the website then you can pass a param in the url to load the desktop site instead